# Is it possible to override dark mode for a form only?

Tags: ios, swiftui

What I want to achieve is a form with a different background color. But I want the items inside always using the light mode variant (dark text colors). But **not** the complete view. I've searched for it but couldn't find any solution.

I've tried `listRowBackground` to change background of the items which works and `preferredColorScheme` to use the light mode but that will make the complete view in light mode:

```
...

Form {

    DatePicker(selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date) { ... }
        .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)

    TextField("Name", text: $name)
        .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)

    Picker("amount", selection: $amount) {
        ForEach(amounts, id: \.self) {
            Text($0)
        }
    }
    .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)

    Button(action: { ... }) {
        Label("More", systemImage: "chevron.up")
    }
    .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)

}
.preferredColorScheme(.light)

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.environment` to force the color scheme of the view:

```
.environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
```

If you don't want to do this for the whole form, you can inject it to the nested views only:

```
Form {
    Group {
        DatePicker(selection: $date, displayedComponents: .date) { ... }
            .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)

        TextField("Name", text: $name)
            .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)

        Picker("amount", selection: $amount) {
            ForEach(amounts, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)

        Button(action: { ... }) {
            Label("More", systemImage: "chevron.up")
        }
        .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)
    }
    .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
}
```

(or to a single view only)

```
Form {
    // ...

    TextField("Name", text: $name)
        .listRowBackground(Color.yellow)
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and also updates the complete view to light mode.

Comment: @Bobbify I'm not sure if I fully understand your answer but please see the update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foregroundColor(Color.black)` or `accentColor(Color.black)` for this work:

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var string: String = String()
    
    @State var selectedColor: Int = 2
    let colorArray: [String] = ["Black", "Blue", "Gray", "Green"]

    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            Text("This text has a dark text color!")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .padding()
    
            TextField("Enter your text here. . .", text: $string)
                .background(Color.red)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)

            Picker(selection: $selectedColor, label: Text(String())) {

                ForEach(colorArray.indices, id: \.self) { index in

                    Text(colorArray[index])
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    
                }

            }

            
            Text("This text has a normal text color!")
                .foregroundColor(Color.primary)
                .padding()
            
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.red)
        .cornerRadius(10)
  
    }
}
```

Comment: This does work for normal text elements, but not for form elements like datpicker, textfield and picker. These have things like placeholder, label and active states.

Comment: I've issues with the placeholder text of a textfield and the chevron of the picker which are not changing color.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I've managed to get it working (less code) with the solution of @pawello2222.

Comment: @Bobbify: happy to hear it, both way are good and less code,  what ever solve your issue use it no problem.